# Is it possible to decide a thread's stack location in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, virtual-memory

I'm doing a project where I need full control over the address space of the process. I need to move the thread's stack away from where it currently is to a predefined area chosen by me, because I need to deallocate the original stack memory. I couldn't find anything on how to do this, only how to deal with the stack size, but that's not what I need. I have two ideas how to do this, none of them being ideal:

- Set ESP and EBP to my predefined area and update the stack base and stack limit fields in the thread's TEB. This sounds like a bad idea since it's hard to know if there are other places I would have to update as well, let alone the possibility of the kernel keeping bookkeeping information internally about the stack's location.
- Reserve memory everywhere to basically force a new thread's stack to be allocated in the space that I've left available. This is an awful idea, I know.

Is it at all possible to do something like this? It doesn't have to be the same thread.

**Edit:** Anything will do as long I get to deallocate the original stack and decide the new/old stack's new location. So copying/moving the stack, killing the old thread and starting a new one with a stack at a predefined location etc. should do just fine. I don't need the old thread, I just need a way to force a thread to run at a certain location (already solved) and have its stack in a safe location decided by me. So in that case it's fine to discard the old stack data as currently I don't depend on it.

Comment: Is it permissible for you to allocate your own memory, build a stack there and use it rather than trying to "move" the existing stack?  Because you really can't do that.. You could copy it, however.

Comment: at which point you want move thread stack ? if before thread begin execute in user mode or say just before thread EP begin executed - think, possible. but at random time, when thread already executed - 100% impossible. how about for example with pointers to variables in stack ? and main - what sense try do this ?

Comment: Simple answer is no.

Comment: Updated the question with an edit.

Comment: "killing old thread" !? copy stack, while can be pointers to old stack location ?! and sense do this ?

Comment: @RbMm I don't need anything on the current stack, so that won't be a problem. I already added this to the edit, but perhaps a bit too late, my bad.

Comment: @Mikubyte - " I don't need anything on the current stack" - the thread/process is your ? you exactly know what thread doing ? you sure that nobody have pointers to old thread stack ? and main - you not reply - what sense do this ? for what ?

Comment: and say for example thread have windows (GUI thread) - you killing it. so all windows will be destroyed. if thread have pending IO operations - all they will be canceled. APC - discarded.. killing thread and recreate new - this is strong I be say..

Comment: @RbMm The process I'm manipulating is completely fresh, I'm literally forcing it to do nothing from the get go, so most likely there is no references or dependencies on anything. I'm clearing the address space completely, hence why it's problematic that the stack exists somewhere out there, so I need to deallocate it. I can't kill the thread since then the process exits, so I can either start a new thread or move the stack of the old one. Just starting a new thread won't work since the stack will be allocated somewhere I don't want it to, which would bring me back to square one.

Comment: In modern versions of Windows (meaning anything from this century, at least) you are not in control of all of the threads in your process.  Third-party software or Windows itself may create new threads outside of your control.  The same goes for the address space; if the operating system has decided, for its own reasons, to allocate a particular part of the address space before your code gets control, there's nothing you can (safely) do about it.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to run your "special" code - whatever it is you are doing that requires direct control over the entire address space, a scenario Windows simply is not designed to meet - inside a virtual machine, with no operating system, or perhaps some suitably chosen third-party operating system.  I imagine it would be possible to set up some form of communication between the "special" code inside the VM and the outside process, and proxy file system requests, user interface, etc., through that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to free the the system allocate stack you are opening a can of worms. The problem is that you need to know the structure of all the stack frames above your thread. These frames could reference addresses on the stack so deleting them could cause all kinds of problems.

You could create a thread with a 1-page stack and not deallocate it. Then allocate your own block of memory and move its address into the stack pointer register. in your top level thread routine.